# 3D graphic app development solution for AT91(cortex A5 ARM without GPU)

Tags: linux, arm

i'm trying to develop an 3D graphic application on my SAMA5D34-EK board(cortex A5 ARM without GPU), seems the openGL cannot be used.

Anyone can tell me some other alternative solution to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Mesa 3D's software renderer](http://www.mesa3d.org), it's essentially OpenGL implemented all in software.

Your CPU [seems to have](http://www.atmel.se/Images/Atmel_11121S_32-bit-Cortex-A5-Microcontroller_SAMA5D3_Summary-Datasheet.pdf.pdf) *some* graphics-acceleration built-in, so if you could use that perhaps you'd gain performance. Probably not though, all the linked-in document says is:

> [The] peripheral set includes an LCD controller with overlays for hardware-accelerated image composition [...]

So that might be too narrowly focused to be useful in a general-purpose rendering solution. I didn't chase down any more detailed documentation, so it's hard to be sure.

Also, using such acceleration might mean writing your own low-level engine/renderer though, which would probably be a very large project.

Comment: I have successfully build and installed Mesa for my Host Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, everything looks good, and the demos works fine. But when i try to cross-compiling Mesa for my ARM-linux boad, there are always give the error as below: checking python2 module: libxml2... no
configure: error: failed to find required module libxml2 i don't know why and tried to find solutions from it, but none of those tips from internet can works for me, i am quite sure i have correctly installed the libxml2 for my system.

Comment: I have sourced the environment-setup file of the root-file system of my arm target before cross-compiling Mesa, is it because there are something missing in my rootfs ? but seems that libxml2 has been included into the rootfs: i can find libxml2.so.2.9 under the usr/lib dir of rootfs, i get confused, why the libxml2 cannot be found during the ./configure progress?

Comment: by the way, when i type:  python -c "import libxml2" in the terminal after sourcing the environment-setup file of the rootfs, i gte error msg as below:**                                           python -c "import libxml2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named libxml2
but after i sourcing the environment-setup file, however when i do it before sourcing the environment-setup file, there is no error at all. Do u have any idea about that, Could  u give me more comments, thx.

Comment: @user3065228 I'm sorry, this is not a general discussion forum. Post more questions if you have specific programming questions.

Comment: So could u tell me how to implement the Mesa software rendering for my board ? Seems there are not enough instructions to do it. My CPU only have the "Floating point unit", is it the graphics-acceleration u mentioned ?

Comment: @user3065228 No, I meant the compositioning support mentioned in the document I linked to. I added a quote to the answer above. Answering how to implement Mesa is a bit too broad, even if it were posted as an actual question.